# Rails both way relationship between two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

In Ruby on Rails I'm trying to be able to create both way many-to-many relationship between two tables. I want a relationship in routes and controllers. For example I want to be able to do both of the things below:

`teachers = school_class.teachers.all`
`school_classes = teacher.school_classes.all`
So if you could help me with the routing setup, controllers and the model for this problem I would appreciate it.

I tried using a has_and_belongs_to_many association and I think that is the right way to go but I couldn't figure out anything else.

Comment: So perhaps you want to share your models with us so that we can help

Answer (score 1):

When you have a `many-to-many` relationship between two tables, you necessarily need a relationship table between them.

[image: relationship_table]

So first create a model that will create your relationship table.

```rb
rails g model TeacherSchoolClass teacher:reference school_class:reference
```

Then in your `models/teacher_school_class.rb`, add the `belongs_to` lines.

```rb
class TeacherSchoolClass < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :school_class
end
```

Finally in both `models/teacher.rb` and `models/school_class.rb`, add the `has_many/through` lines.

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teacher_school_classes, dependent: :destroy # Will destroy the related teacher_school_classes when teacher is destroyed
  has_many :school_classes, through: :teacher_school_classes # Will get all the school_classes for this teacher through the teacher_school_classes table
end

class SchoolClass < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teacher_school_classes, dependent: :destroy # Will destroy the related teacher_school_classes when school_class is destroyed
  has_many :teachers, through: :teacher_school_classes # Will get all the teachers for this school_class through the teacher_school_classes table
end
```

You will then be able to get:

- all the school classes for a specific teacher
- all the teachers for a specific school class

```rb
teacher.school_classes # Returns an ActiveRecord::Relation of SchoolClass
school_class.teachers # Returns an ActiveRecord::Relation of Teacher
```

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association